# Securing Azure Functions and on-premises to Azure Sql calls

Tags: security, ssl, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

- Say we have a 3rd party vendor trying to call an Azure function, how do we secure the communication channel? Using ssl?
- How do we secure communication from on-premises to Azure Sql? [beyond PAT tokens, I want the communication line into Azure encrypted]. We do have Azure AD from on-premises to Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Securing Azure Function :** 
When you deploy Azure function the endpoint is publically available so you can access them.

One way is to put the function in ILBASE and put [WAF in front of ILBASE](https://sabbour.me/how-to-run-an-app-service-behind-a-waf-enabled-application-gateway/). In this way your functions endpoints are not exposed publically directly but yes this is quite costly .
In this you will have full control over the traffic and then you can enable SSL .

Second would be put SSL as you have mentioned.

Third Option would be to authenticate your user from Azure AD with function app.

Fourth option would be to use managed identies with function app.

**For secure communication from on-premises to Azure Sql :**

This can also be achived by couple of ways. But I belive the easiest way to use [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#how-it-works). 
The connection uses TLS 1.2 for security and shared access signature (SAS) keys for authentication and authorization